# Fixing Errors (Haskell) Simple Snakes & Ladder Game

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, ambiguous

today I am here to request any helping to sort out the 5~ unique errors I have left to compile this Snakes & Ladder Game. I am providing the errors I am getting below and also the code.

I am providing all the information I feel is necessary to provide me some pointers. Thank you in advance. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Main.hs:10:88:
   Ambiguous occurrence ‘concat’
   It could refer to either 'Data.List.concat'
   imported from ‘Data.List’ at Main.hs:3:1-16
                                (and originally defined in ‘GHC.List’)
                             or ‘Data.Foldable.concat’,
                                imported from ‘Data.Foldable’ at Main.hs:5:1-20

Main.hs:10:96:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘replicate’
    It could refer to either 'Data.List.replicate'
    imported from ‘Data.List.replicate’ at Main.hs:3:1-16
                               (and originally defined in ‘GHC.List’)
                            or ‘Data.Sequence.replicate’,
                               imported from ‘Data.Sequence’ at Main.hs:4:1-20

Main.hs:10:96:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘elem’
    It could refer to either 'Data.List.elem'
    imported from ‘Data.List’ at Main.hs:3:1-16
                               (and originally defined in ‘GHC.List’)
                            or ‘Data.Foldable.elem’,
                                imported from ‘Data.Sequence’ at Main.hs:5:1-20

Main.hs:17:48:
  Not in scope: pos’
  Perhaps you meant ‘pos’ (line 14) 

Main.hs:43:37: Not in scope: ‘nums’
```

Here is the code:

```
module Main where

import Data.List
import Data.Sequence
import Data.Foldable
import Control.Lens

data Game = G Int Int Int [Int] [Bool] [Bool] [Bool] [Int] [Property] Int
data Property = Int | E | A | D
displayRow game@(G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) n = unlines [ '+' : concat (replicate n "---+") , '|' : concat (replicate n "   |")]
display game@(G 0 cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) = ""
display game@(G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) = (displayRow game cols) ++ display (G (rows - 1) cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn)
go game@(G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props 0) _ = display game
go game@(G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) i
  | elem (rows*cols) pos = display game 
  | nplayers == i = go (G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props (turn - 1)) 0 
  | otherwise = go (move (G rows cols nplayers pos' e a d (tail drolls) props turn) i roll) (i + 1) where
    roll = if d!!i then 2*(head drolls) else (head drolls)
move (G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) i j = case (elemIndex posij pos) of
  Just k -> (move (G rows cols nplayers pos' e' a' d' drolls props turn) k 1) 
  Nothing -> (G rows cols nplayers pos' e' a' d' drolls props turn) 
  where
    posij = if (pos!!i + j) > rows*cols then rows*cols else pos!!i + j 
    pos'
      | props!!posij > posij = if e!!i then pos & ix i .~ (2*(props!!posij) - posij) else pos & ix i .~ (props!!posij)
      | props!!posij < posij = if a!!i then pos & ix i .~ posij else pos & ix i .~ (props!!posij)
      | otherwise = pos & ix i .~ posij
    e'
      | props!!posij > posij = if e!!i then e & ix i .~ False else e
      | props!!posij == E = e & ix i .~ True
      | otherwise = e
    a'
      | props!!posij < posij = if a!!i then a & ix i .~ False else a
      | props!!posij == A = a & ix i .~ True
      | otherwise = a
    d' = if (props!!posij) == D then (d & ix i .~ True) else (d & ix i .~ False)
instance Show Game where
  show game@(G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) = go game 0 
build (l:ls) = build' (G 0 0 0 [] [] [] [] [] [] 0) (l:ls) where
  build' game (l:ls) = build' (update game l) ls
  build' game [] = game
  update (G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) s = case (words s) of
                    "board":l -> G (nums!!0) (nums!!1) nplayers pos e a d drolls [i | i <- [0..(nums!!0)*(nums!!1)]] turn
                    "players":l -> G rows cols (nums!!0) [0 | _ <- [1..(nums!!0)]] [False | _ <- [1..(nums!!0)]] [False | _ <- [1..(nums!!0)]] [False | _ <- [1..(nums!!0)]] drolls props turn
                    "dice":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d (cycle nums) props turn
                    "ladder":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls (props & ix (nums!!0) .~ (nums!!1)) turn
                    "snake":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls (props & ix (nums!!0) .~ (nums!!1)) turn
                    "powerup":"escalator":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls (over (elements (flip elem nums)) (const E) props) turn
                    "powerup":"antivenom":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls (over (elements (flip elem nums)) (const A) props) turn
                    "powerup":"double":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls (over (elements (flip elem nums)) (const D) props) turn
                    "turns":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d nums props (turn + (nums!!0)) where
                      nums = map read l :: [Int]
readFrom input = build (lines input)
main = do
  input <- getContents
  putStr $ show $ readFrom input
```

Comment: Why are you importing `Data.Sequence`? Anyway, if you need that, you must disambiguate the function calls highlighted by the compiler. E.g. use `Data.List.elem` instead of the bare `elem` if that must be taken from the `Data.List` import.

Comment: please format your code, right now all the where clauses seem to be off, also get in the habit of adding type signatures to your top-level definitions, this helps both the compiler and everyone else reading your code figuring out what you intended the code to do. Also a few extra lines wouldn't be bad!

Comment: You should import `Data.List` qualified (`import qualified Data.List as List`) or not at all. `Data.Foldable` has strictly more generic functions than `Data.List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code formatted for sanity, and with type signatures added:

```
module Main where

import Data.Foldable
import Control.Lens

data Game = G Int Int Int [Int] [Bool] [Bool] [Bool] [Int] [Property] Int

data Property = Int | E | A | D

displayRow :: Game -> Int -> String
displayRow game@(G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) n = unlines [ '+' : concat (replicate n "---+") , '|' : concat (replicate n "   |")]

display :: Game -> String
display game@(G 0 cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) = ""
display game@(G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) = (displayRow game cols) ++ display (G (rows - 1) cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn)

go :: Game -> Int -> String
go game@(G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props 0) _ = display game
go game@(G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) i
  | elem (rows*cols) pos = display game
  | nplayers == i = go (G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props (turn - 1)) 0
  | otherwise = go (move (G rows cols nplayers pos' e a d (tail drolls) props turn) i roll) (i + 1)
    where
      roll = if d!!i then 2*(head drolls) else (head drolls)

move :: Game -> Int -> Int -> Game
move (G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) i j = case (elemIndex posij pos) of
  Just k -> (move (G rows cols nplayers pos' e' a' d' drolls props turn) k 1)
  Nothing -> (G rows cols nplayers pos' e' a' d' drolls props turn)
  where
    posij = if (pos!!i + j) > rows*cols then rows*cols else pos!!i + j
    pos'
      | props!!posij > posij = if e!!i then pos & ix i .~ (2*(props!!posij) - posij) else pos & ix i .~ (props!!posij)
      | props!!posij < posij = if a!!i then pos & ix i .~ posij else pos & ix i .~ (props!!posij)
      | otherwise = pos & ix i .~ posij
    e'
      | props!!posij > posij = if e!!i then e & ix i .~ False else e
      | props!!posij == E = e & ix i .~ True
      | otherwise = e
    a'
      | props!!posij < posij = if a!!i then a & ix i .~ False else a
      | props!!posij == A = a & ix i .~ True
      | otherwise = a
    d' = if (props!!posij) == D then (d & ix i .~ True) else (d & ix i .~ False)

instance Show Game where
  show game@(G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) = go game 0

build :: [String] -> Game
build (l:ls) = build' (G 0 0 0 [] [] [] [] [] [] 0) (l:ls) 
  where
    build' game (l:ls) = build' (update game l) ls
    build' game [] = game

update :: Game -> String -> Game
update (G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls props turn) s = case (words s) of
    "board":l -> G (nums!!0) (nums!!1) nplayers pos e a d drolls [i | i <- [0..(nums!!0)*(nums!!1)]] turn
    "players":l -> G rows cols (nums!!0) [0 | _ <- [1..(nums!!0)]] [False | _ <- [1..(nums!!0)]] [False | _ <- [1..(nums!!0)]] [False | _ <- [1..(nums!!0)]] drolls props turn
    "dice":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d (cycle nums) props turn
    "ladder":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls (props & ix (nums!!0) .~ (nums!!1)) turn
    "snake":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls (props & ix (nums!!0) .~ (nums!!1)) turn
    "powerup":"escalator":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls (over (elements (flip elem nums)) (const E) props) turn
    "powerup":"antivenom":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls (over (elements (flip elem nums)) (const A) props) turn
    "powerup":"double":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d drolls (over (elements (flip elem nums)) (const D) props) turn
    "turns":l -> G rows cols nplayers pos e a d nums props (turn + (nums!!0))
    where
      nums = map read l :: [Int]

readFrom :: String -> Game
readFrom input = build (lines input)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  input <- getContents
  putStr $ show $ readFrom input
```

Your errors were caused by importing `Data.List` and `Data.Sequence`, which both provided functions with the same names as functions in the Prelude and each other, so they had a name conflict and ambiguous names.

Work from here and update with specific problems if you encounter any, and make sure to include what you have tried to do to solve the issues.

Comment: I would like to start by saying thank you. This alone has helped me understand so much more about functional programming. Your changes coupled with a little extra helping me get rid of majority of the errors. I now seem to be receiving **Main.hs:20:1: parse error on input ' | ' **. I also got these errors before and did some research but people had different approaches solving this problem. Many recommended changing the code entirely. I am wondering if a small change with my existing code could get rid of this error. I also noticed once, i fixed once parse error, another one came forward.Thank

Comment: I am aware regarding the indentation rules of Haskell but I think your formatted code for my sanity fixes those concerns. I wonder if it is concerning indentation of the guards in specific? (But they seem to be indented above.. Thanks

Comment: @MoeChong There are some architectural changes that people probably recommended, and I would follow that advice. Your `Game` data type is very unwieldy, and would benefit from record syntax. As for indentation of pattern guards in `where` blocks, I have no idea. I would rewrite those functions into top-level declarations if I were you. If you haven't already, I would build up your understanding of Haskell syntax by reading the first few chapters of an introductory text like [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

Comment: I made some further changes, removing 'import Data.Foldable' got rid of some more errors. After changing some spaces and tab issues, I got majority of the indentation also fixed. Here are the remaining errors [link](https://pastebin.com/def5yKGD). Could you help me understand/sort them. I just want this code to compile once. Thank you again for your quick help, I cant thank you enough.

Comment: @MoeChong "Not in scope" means that the variable isn't known at a specific spot. The "21:48" means line 21, character 48. `pos'` is different from `pos`.